# Pulling out Popular terms from a Solr core

Tags: solr

I have an Apache Solr core where i need to pull out the popular terms out of it, i am already aware of [luke](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler), [facets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview), and Apache Solr [stopwords](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) but i am not getting what i want, for example, when i try to use luke to get the popular terms and after applying the stopwords on the result set i get a bunch of words like:

http, img, que ...etc

While what i really want is:

Obama, Metallica, Samsung ...etc

Is there any better way to implement this in Solr?, am i missing something that should be used to do this?

Thank You

Comment: So you want something like "Just fetch me nouns and names"?

Answer (score 3):

Finding *relevant* words from a text is not easy. The first thing I would have a deeper look at is *Natural Language Processing (NLP)* with Solr. The [article in Solr's wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP) is a starting point for this. Reading the page you will stumble over the *[Full Example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP#Full_Example)* which extracts nouns and verbs, probably that already helps you.

During the process of getting this running you will need to install additional software (Apache's OpenNLP project) so after reading in Solr's wiki [that project's home page](http://opennlp.apache.org/) maybe the next step.

To get a feeling what is possible with that you should have a look on [the demonstration of the searchbox](http://www.searchbox.com/products/searchbox-plugins/demo/) guy. There you can paste a sample text and get relevant words and terms extracted from it.

There are [several tutorials out there](https://www.google.de/search?q=solr%20nlp%20tutorial) you may have a look at for further reading.

---

If you went down the path and the results are not as expected or not as good as required, you may go down that road even further and start thinking about text mining with [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/). There are again [several tutorials out there](https://www.google.de/search?q=solr%20mahout) to cross it with Solr.

---

In any case you should then search Stackoverflow or the web for tutorials and How-Tos you will certainly need.

---

**Update about arabic**

If you are going to use OpenNLP for not supported languages, which [Arabic unfortunately is](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) out of the box as of version 1.5, you will need to *train* OpenNLP for the language. The reference about it is found on [the developer docs of OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html). Probably there is already something out there from the arabic community, but my arabic google-fu is not that good.

Should you decide to do the work and train it for the arabic language, why not share your traning with the project?

**Update about integration in Solr/Lucene**

There is work going on to [integrate it as a module](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2899). In my humble opinion this is as far as it will and should get. If you compare this problem field [to stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) stemming appears to be rather easy. But even stemming got complex when supporting different languages. Analysing a language to the level that you can extract nouns, verbs and so forth is so complex that a whole *project* evolved around it.

Having a module/contrib at hand, which you could simply copy to solr_home/lib would already be very handy. So there would be no need to run a different installer an so forth.

Comment: This is a pretty nice answer that i would vote up, but this implies a lot of work to be done and a lot of tutorials and articles to read and indeed a big learning curve to climb up, i was hoping to get something a lil bit easier, i mean this thing is pretty natural and i wonder why it is not implemented with solr core instead of integration with external components, am i right on this? ohh i forgot to say Thank you, So thank you for your nice answer :)

Comment: Also i wonder if the propused solution would work with different languages, for instance i am planing to use this for Arabic content, is the Arabic language supported by this solution? Thanks again for your kind help

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I updated my answer, since the reply got a bit lengthy :)

Comment: Thank you so much, youre answer is amazing just like you :) Thanks alot buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Well , this is a bit open ended. 
First you will need to facet and find "popular terms" out of your index, then add all the non useful items such as http , img , time , what, when etc to your stop word list and re-index to get cream of the data you care about. I do not think there is an easier way of knowing popular names unless you can bounce your data against a custom dictionary of nouns during indexing (that is an option by the way)- You can choose to index only names by having a custom token filter (look how stopword filter works) and have your own nouns.txt file to go with your own nouns filter, in the case you allow only words in your dictionary to into index, and this approach is only possible if you have finite known list of nouns.

Comment: Thansk for your suggestion but i don't think that this would make the best implementation, since the stopwords list is going to grow and everytime an item is being added to the list i have to re-index the data, is there anyway to use stopwords filters with terms component or facets on the fly?

Comment: I voted cheffe's answer up. i went through his answer and links, very useful.